# Cypress for Electron - Using FS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, cypress, fs

I am using Cypress to test my Electron application.
Since Cypress uses the browser mode, `FS` is not supported.
So I am getting this error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function"
```

And I found this on the documentation:

> https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Event

So I added this on my test:

```
it('Sample test', () => {
  cy.task('readSettingsJson', settingsFolder).then((content) => { 
    // This can print the JSON file contents correctly
    console.log('content = ' + content) 
  })
})
```

And on my `plugins/index.js`:

```
 on('task', {
    readSettingsJson(foldername) {
      if (!fs.existsSync(foldername)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(foldername, { recursive: true })
        // some command to copy the file
      } else {
        // This is what I am testing at this moment
        return fs.readFileSync(path.join(filename, '/settings.json'), 'utf8')
      }

      return null
    }
 })
```

However, it doesnt seem to work. I still get the error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function"
```

And despite the test printing the json file correctly, my app still can't load the JSON file.

Am I missing anything? Help please!

Comment: Task errors show up in the terminal, but browser errors are in the console. Where are you seeing the error after introducing the task?

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker - Thank you for your response. I am seeing the second error at the console (dev tools window).. ```vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function"```

Comment: The error indicates it is thrown by the Vue app (not the Cypress test or task). To use `fs.existsSync` in a Vue app hosted by Electron, you need to have Vue make IPC calls to the Electron backend which can then run `fs.existsSync`  and send back a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress support for Electron apps are in very early alpha release:
https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/09/26/testing-electron-js-applications-using-cypress-alpha-release/

As an alternative, try using Spectron, which is the testing framework that is currently recommended by Electron team:
https://www.electronjs.org/spectron

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I know that Electron is not 'officially' supported yet by Cypress. But specifically for my question (that being ```fs``` usage), Cypress task should be able to handle it. So I want to know what am I missing based on the this guide: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Event.

Comment: This is no longer the case; the team is deprecating Spectron: https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron/issues/1045